# Spotfire - Dividing one row value with another in a cross table

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I have a cross table which shows fruits sold across months as shown below:
[image: Table 1]]

Now, I would like to see a table (shown below) which divides one cell with another for a particular column:
[image: Table 2]]

Please let me know if this is possible with an OVER statement.

---

**UPDATE:**

@Chris - I have transformed my original table in access and could create the below cross table visualization in Spotfire.

Note: Apples sold, Oranges sold, watermelons sold are now separate columns after applying transformation.

[Cross table visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NatXU.jpg)

However, I would like to see the cross table in the format below.

[Transposed table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUHA.jpg)

Please let me know if this is possible. If this could be achieved with Iron Python script, I am fine with that.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your data is in a tall skinny format, my original answer didn't work. I've kept the answer as part of this in case it helps someone else, see below.

With your update, you seem to have managed to create a crosstable with the data you want. While it would be helpful if you could show your exact axis expression on row-, column- and measure axis, I can try to illustrate how to transpose the data in the cross table as you want it to. See the last last section for an explanation.

With a tall skinny format, you will not be able to use an OVER expression as you are looking to do explicit comparisons (at least I don't think it's possible). First I'd like to note that you have to decide somehow which fruits you want to compare to each other, or you might want to compare all of them. The exact solution would depend on what your real use case is and how dynamic you need it to be.

### Possible solution:

In your crosstable, define your row axis as (column names):

```
<[Axis.Default.Names]>
```

Put your time axis on the column axis, for instance:

```
<BinByDateTime([Time],"Year.Month",1)>
```

On your measure axis, you will now add all the comparisons you are interested in, such as:

```
Sum(if([Fruit]="Apple", [Sold],null)) / Sum(if([Fruit]="Watermelon",[Sold],null)) as [Apples vs Watermelons],
Sum(if([Fruit]="Orange",[Sold],null)) / Sum(if([Fruit]="Watermelon",[Sold],null)) as [Oranges vs Watermelons]
```

Here's a link to how this looks with my own very small dummy dataset:
[image: Example crosstable result]

It's possible you can combine this with user controls in a text area, and maybe the *$map()* expression function to make it more dynamic if needed.
If you want a lot of dynamic behavior in this you might need to change to use a datafunction instead.

---

### Old answer

Below is my original answer, that includes presumption about the data that didn't apply in this case. Keeping it here if anyone else actually have this situation.

In table 1 you have two categorical axes, one for time and one for fruit. And the measure you are showing is the quantity of sold fruits.

In table 2 I'd say that you only have one categorical axis, time. After that, you have two measured values, and your row axis would be '(Column Names)'.

The measures would be the count of apples divided by the count of oranges, as well as the count of oranges divided by the count of watermelons. If you'd right click the measure axis and go to custom expression you would have something like:

```
Sum([Apples]) / Sum([Oranges]) as [Apples vs. Oranges], 
Sum([Oranges]) / Sum([Watermelons]) as [Oranges vs. Watermelons]
```

Also, go to Properties -> Formatting and set your percentage formatting to your liking.

### Transpose in cross table

It's a bit hard to understand from your screenshots, so I'll guess what your axis expressions are. Even if I guess wrong, the same approach is applicable regardless initial state. You just need to swap the row axis with the column axis. You can do it by using the axis selectors, or copy and paste from the custom expression editor. If this is the kind of configuration you have from the start:
[image: Original crosstable configuration]

Then by swapping the axis expressions this is what you get:
[image: Transposed crosstable configuration]

Comment: Thank you Chris for the solution. Just to clarify, Apples, oranges etc are part of a column 'Fruit Type'. They are not individual columns. I am trying to divide sum([Fruit Type].[apples])/sum([Fruit Type].[oranges]). I am not sure as how to refer to row items in a particular column in custom expression.

Comment: @ksp: In that case my answer is incorrect. I'll let it stay there to let it be an example in case another has data that is structured in the way I presumed. OVER statement will not be able to give you what you want in this case, you need to work with your data more (as far as I know). I can give a new answer with more details, but the complexity of a solution depends on how flexible you want it to be.

Comment: @Chris- I have added more details to my original question. Please check and let me know if the solution I am looking for is possible. Thank you!

Comment: @ksp: In your new example, if the 'Cross table visualization' is a cross table, you would get the 'Transposed table' by just switching the row and column axis expression with each other.

Comment: @Chris- I tried doing that. sum([Apples sold]), sum([oranges sold]) etc are repeating for each month across columns.

Comment: @ksp: Sounds like you have moved the row axis expression (the time) onto to the column axis, but haven't moved the expression that was on the column axis to the row axis. Does that help? Otherwise I can explain in greater detail.

Comment: @Chris- Request you to explain in detail. Thank you!

Comment: @ksp: I have added a section on how to transpose the data in a cross table.

Comment: Thanks so much Chris! I am able to transpose the table now in the format that I am looking for.